# How to get a blob data by using putExtra/setExtra?

Tags: android, image, imageview, blob

I have tried this code. where is the wrong?

In 1st activity:

```
Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getdata(Adapter.KEY_RID, _id);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("image",getImage(d.getBlob(d.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_IMG))));
//intent.putExtra("image",d.getBlob(d.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_IMG)));
```

in second activity:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
iv.setImageBitmap(getIntent().getStringExtra("image"));
//iv.setImageBitmap(getImage(getIntent().getStringExtra("image")));
```

and get Image:

```
 public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
```

Comment: why you do that?? better to send URL or Image name and load it on second activity

Comment: i have a databae with any blob values

Answer (score 0):

Pass image path in your Intent as `intent.putExtra("ImagePath","YOUR_IMAGE_PATH_OR_URL");` to the next activity.
Then get the image path on next activity like `getIntent().getStringExtra("ImagePath")` and do what ever you want.

Putting the whole image or byte-array of image in intent is not a good approach.

Hope it helps you.